# Swift Custom Variable Type

Tags: swift

For working with complex numbers, this is how I've been doing it:

```
import Foundation

class Complex {
    var real: Float
    var imaginary: Float
    init(re: Float, im: Float) {
        self.imaginary = im
        self.real = re
    }
    func abs() -> Float {
        return sqrtf(powf(self.real, 2) + powf(self.imaginary, 2))
    }

    func string() -> String {
        if (ceilf(self.real) == self.real) && (ceilf(self.imaginary) == self.imaginary){
            return "\(Int(self.real))+\(Int(self.imaginary))i"
        }
            return "\(self.real)+\(self.imaginary)i"
    }

    func arg() -> Float {
            return atan2f(self.imaginary, self.real)
    }
}

var someComplex = Complex(re: 2, im: 3)
var someComplexString = someComplex.string() //"2+3i"
var someComplexAbsolute = someComplex.abs() // 3.60...
var someComplexArgument = someComplex.arg() //0.98...
```

Now I was wondering, if there was any way to define a custom type of variable that would let me write it as `someComplex: Complex = 3i` for example. Is it possible to create a new type "from the ground up"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want to store any kind of value you can define `value` as an `AnyObject` or `Any` type.

Comment: Also class names, by convention, start with an uppercase letter, i.e. `SomeClass`, and variables, even in initializers, start with a lowercase letter, i.e. `init(stringValue: String)`

Comment: Instead of accessing an already existing type in a class (var a = someClass.someValue), assign a value directly to the type (var a = someClass)

Comment: So you want to store the class in a variable itself? I think you can do `SomeClass.self`

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly uncertain if this is what you're looking for, but based on your comment to the other answer

> *"Thanks, but what I meant was something like a custom type that would accept all floats and i for example"*,

you could create a wrapper that holds a single generic value, where the generic type of this value is *type constrained* to some protocol, to which you in turn extend the types you wish to be wrappable but the type. E.g., below allowing types `Int`, `Float` and `String` to be wrapped by the wrapper

```
protocol MyGenericTypes { }

extension Int: MyGenericTypes { }
extension Float: MyGenericTypes { }
extension String: MyGenericTypes { }

struct SomeWrapper<T: MyGenericTypes> {
    var value: T
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let myInt = 42
let myFloat: Float = 4.2
let myString = "forty-two"

let wrappedInt = SomeWrapper(myInt)       // T inferred as "Int"
let wrappedFloat = SomeWrapper(myFloat)   // T inferred as "Float"
let wrappedString = SomeWrapper(myString) // T ingerred as "String"

print(wrappedInt.dynamicType)    // SomeWrapper<Int>
print(wrappedFloat.dynamicType)  // SomeWrapper<Float>
print(wrappedString.dynamicType) // SomeWrapper<String>
```

You can naturally write generic functions allowing arguments for `SomeWrapper<T>` instances, type constraining `T` in the same fashion as in the struct definition above

```
func foo<T: MyGenericTypes>(bar: SomeWrapper<T>) -> () {
    print(bar.value)
}

foo(wrappedInt)    // 4.2
foo(wrappedFloat)  // 42
foo(wrappedString) // forty-two
```